# synchronized before field outside of new Thread()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to make a part of asynchronous. I added a new Thread() and put to it code. What have to be done with fields and methods outside?

```
public class Record {
    private String actionDetails;

    public void setActionDetails(String actionDetails) {
        this.actionDetails = actionDetails;
    }
}

public class Recorder {
    private Record record;

    public void record(Record record){
        this.record = record;
    }
}

public class Test {
    private static Recorder recorder = new Recorder();
    private static StringBuilder builder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        builder.append("Test");

        new Thread(() -> {
            final Record record = new Record();
            record.setActionDetails(builder.toString());
            recorder.record(record);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I think that for recorder, record(), setActionDetails() should use synchronized modificator and use StringBuffer instead StringBuilder.

Comment: The code you have shown does nothing useful, and nothing that benefits from making it multithreaded. The question of "what to do" can only be (usefully) answered with code that is representative of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Exactly. Your current code is guaranteed to work correctly as is in any condition. It doesn’t need any changes.

Comment: As of now you could mark `private String actionDetails;` and `private Record record;` as `volatile` since it assures visibility for changes made to those references to all threads and is more lightweight than `synchronized` block